# 'cannot open input file' error using webp-converter to convert webp to PNG

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, event-handling, webp

## Expected behavior

My event listener below is supposed to:

1. Download a webp.
2. Save it to a temp directory.
3. Pass the file path of the saved webp to the webp.dwebp function.
4. Convert it to a PNG using the webp-converter package function.
5. And finally save that PNG to the the same directory (I'm using a static temp folder for now).

```
//Discord bot Event listener to put the webp image in temp folder and then covert to png
let timer;

client.on(Events.MessageUpdate, (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
    newMessage.attachments.forEach((attachment) => {
        if (attachment.url) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                // Use tmp package to create a temp directory

                //download the image at attachment.url and save it to the temp directory
                request(attachment.url)
                    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`temp/image${attachment.id}.webp`))
                    .on("close", () => {
                        console.log("Image downloaded to temp directory");
                        //convert webp to png
                        webp.dwebp(
                            `temp/image${attachment.id}.webp`,
                            `temp/image${attachment.id}.png`,
                            "-quiet -quiet",
                            function (status, error) {
                                if (status == 100) {
                                    console.log("Successfully converted to PNG");
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Error during conversion: ", error);
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    });
            });
        }
    }, 14000);
});
```

## Actual behavior

I can successfully download the webp to the temp directory, but it fails when trying to convert. I get the following error.

```
Error: Command failed: "C:\Users\mr\camp\discordapi\node_modules\webp-converter\bin\lemp/image1064098822244020244.webp" -quiet -quiet "temp/image1064098822244020244.png" "function
== 100) { console.log("Successfully converted to PNG"); } else { console.log("Error during con
cannot open input file ', error); } }'

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:412:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
  code: 4294967295,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
```

### What I've tried

At first I thought it was a problem with the tmp library I was using, so I cut that out to test and just went with a static /temp folder. Downloading to /temp still works as expected, but I still run into the same error at the webp-to-PNG process.

I tried moving the `webp.dwebp` process outside of the request chain, but that doesn't work because I can't grab the file path variable outside the scope of request function.

My next idea was to append the `attachment.id` to the file path as a UID, to make it easier to find the file webp file and then write a function to construct a path to it outside of the event listener entirely, essentially doing the `webp-dwebp` process by itself.

So I defined an empty `pngImageId` object outside the function to write that `attachment.id` to, so I could find it easily, but got stuck trying to smuggle that variable itself out of the event handler, so same problem.

I just need to convert this pesky webp file to a .PNG so I can send it to the client and render it. Really scratching my head here.